# Listing in the output in a specific crawler

Tags: xpath

i have been making xml template for a specific concern for crawling the jobs of that concern. Am using xpath for making templates but at the the runnable time the crawler is running with out giving error but with out listing the jobs

Eg:the template of Sopra technologies(the url provided in the coding)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<site>
 <request-type>link</request-type>  
  <base-url><![CDATA[http://www.in.sopragroup.com/index.htm]]></base-url>
   <start-url><![CDATA[http://www.in.sopragroup.com/careers/JobListing.aspx]]>
     </start-url>
<data>
<intermediate>
    <navigation-request>
    <navigation-type>link</navigation-type>
    <url>
    <xpath></xpath>

<sub-xpath></sub-xpath>
    </url>
    </navigation-request>
    <xpath><![CDATA[//table[@class='bg_lgrey']/tbody/tr[position>2]]></xpath>
    <apply-url>
    <sub-xpath><![CDATA[td/@href]]></sub-xpath>
    </apply-url>
    <title>
    <sub-xpath><![CDATA[td/a/text()]]></sub-xpath>
    </title>
    </intermediate>
    <detail>
    <xpath><![CDATA[//table[@id='tbl']/tbody]]></xpath>

    <experience>
    <sub-xpath><![CDATA[tr[8]/td[2]/text()]]></sub-xpath>
    </experience>
    <location>
    <sub-xpath><![CDATA[tr[10]/td[2]/text()]]></sub-xpath>
    </location>
    <description>
    <sub-xpath><![CDATA[tr[2]/td[2]/text()]]></sub-xpath>
    </description>
    </detail>
    </data>
</site>
```

Comment: I looked at the source of http://www.in.sopragroup.com/careers/JobListing.aspx with Firefox and searched for `bg_lgrey`, that is not found in the source at all so I don't see how `//table[@class='bg_lgrey']/tbody/tr[position>2]` would find anything

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> //table[@class='bg_lgrey']/tbody/tr[position>2]
> ```

**This is one of the problems** in the code. Such Xpath expression has chances of selecting something only if the `tr` element has a child named `position` whose string value is castable to a number with value greater than 2.

**You want**:

```
//table[@class='bg_lgrey']/tbody/tr[position() >2]
```

**A second problem**:

The string `"bg_lgrey"` is not present at all in the source of the pages pointed by the two urls.